# Run Jupyter Notebooks/Sagemath on Sublime Text

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sublimetext4

I am trying to run Jupyter notebooks on the Sublime Text editor. I discovered this plugin which can be installed via Package Control, namely Helium. However, after installing, I couldn't find the option "Helium: Connect Kernel", which is inconsistent with what the usage part of the project's GitHub README tells me to expect. There is no error message anywhere to guide me.

If knowing the architecture helps, I am using an M2 Silicon Chip MacBook Air with MacOS 14 Sonoma.

I eventually plan to try running this software called Sagemath on my editor, and I conjecture that being able to run Jupyter notebooks on my editor will help in this process. I have asked a question on the software's corresponding forum, but if someone already has the know-how for this, please let me know!

No, please don't ask me to change my editor, thank you.